# Select only appended child

Tags: jquery, addclass, css-selectors

I want to apply the class only to  dynamically created divs.

HTML:

```
<div id="pbody">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
    <div>d</div>
    <div>e</div>
</div>


<button class="add">Add</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','.add',function(){

   $('#pbody').append('<div>f</div><div>g</div><div>h</div><div>i</div><div>j</div><div>k</div><div>l</div>').addClass('active');

});
```

I know it's wrong, but is there a way I can **select only the divs that I append**, or is there a way to (say) select between 5th child and 10th child in jQuery?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4PYC

Comment: you need to have some unique property to identify the appended items probably add a class to all the new divs

Comment: do you want to add the class active to the newly added items

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes the new ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is to add the class active to the newly added items, then you can use [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) instead of [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) as given below

```
$('<div>f</div><div>g</div><div>h</div><div>i</div><div>j</div><div>k</div><div>l</div>').appendTo('#pbody').addClass('active');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zd7MP/)

Comment: tnx works perfectly. Is there a way to select only the divs appended.. so that i can extract something from appended divs only ,using each?

Answer (score 0):

just change the order of your chained methods a bit:

```
   $('<div>f</div><div>g</div><div>h</div><div>i</div><div>j</div><div>k</div><div>l</div>')
   .addClass('active')
   .appendTo('#pbody');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4PYC/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).on('click','.add',function(){
                    // added classname for all the append div elements
                 $('#pbody').append('<div class="appendHtml">f</div><div class="appendHtml">g</div><div class="appendHtml">h</div><div class="appendHtml">i</div><div class="appendHtml">j</div><div class="appendHtml">k</div><div class="appendHtml">l</div>').addClass('active');

                    $(".appendHtml").each(function( index, value ) {
                        console.log( index + ": " + value );                            
                    });
            });

        </script>
```

OR

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).on('click','.add',function(){

               $('<div>f</div><div>g</div><div>h</div><div>i</div><div>j</div><div>k</div><div>l</div>').addClass('appendHtml').appendTo('#pbody');
                    $(".appendHtml").each(function( index, value ) {
                        console.log( index + ": " + value );                            
                    });
                 });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.add',function(){ 
   $('#pbody').append('<div>f</div><div>g</div><div>h</div><div>i</div><div>j</div><div>k</div><div>l</div>');
   $("#pbody div:gt(5)").addClass('active'); 
});
```

check http://jsfiddle.net/alaminopu/Q4PYC/3/